# tensorflow from indexes to values

Tags: tensorflow, mapping

let's suppose I have a tensor with inside integers that represent indexes of a list, and I want to replace them with the associated values from an array. It is like an hashtable but I gave up with that since it told me that was not initialized (waste too much time really). 
So let's suppose I have a tensor like:

`[[1,2,3],[2,0,1],[0,3,1]]` and an array of 4 elements array(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8)

and I would like to have as result `[[0.4,0.6,0.8],[0.6,0.2,0.4],[0.2,0.6,0.4]]`

how can I do in tensorflow in order to have it in the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need `tf.gather` method

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [2, 0, 1], [0, 3, 1]])
y = tf.constant([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
output = tf.gather(y, x)
print output.eval()
array([[ 0.40000001,  0.60000002,  0.80000001],
      [ 0.60000002,  0.2       ,  0.40000001],
      [ 0.2       ,  0.80000001,  0.40000001]], dtype=float32)
```

Visit https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather for more information

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
idx=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,0,1],[0,3,1]])
l=tf.constant([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8])
res=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(l,idx)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

This prints

```
array([[ 0.40000001,  0.60000002,  0.80000001],
       [ 0.60000002,  0.2       ,  0.40000001],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.80000001,  0.40000001]], dtype=float32)
```